# how to specify the store to publish using collection FS package in meteor? ( performance issue )

Tags: performance, meteor, store, publish, collectionfs

i have an image collection with multiple store ( original, thumbs, crops, etc ....) and i don't always need them all at the same time.  So it will be very interesting from a performance perspective to be able to choose the which store to publish each time.

Please is it possible ?

Comment: Are you actually having a performance problem or thinking about a future one? If you're having a current problem can you show code and timings?

Comment: here is a snippet of how the images collection look like :  Images = new FS.Collection("Images", {
 stores: [
  new FS.Store.GridFS("original"),
  new FS.Store.GridFS("crops", {transformWrite: createCrop}),
  new FS.Store.GridFS("thumbs", { transformWrite: createThumb })

 ],  about the timing:  with say 20-30 of such images the view takes arround 1 second to render.

Comment: I don't believe your stores are your problem. When you publish your `Images` collection you are only publishing the image _metadata_. It's only when you load the `.url()` of an image into an `img` tag that you are moving image bytes. So if you're only showing thumbnails on the page that's all the bytes you're going to get.

Comment: Ok thanks for this clarifications, you are probably right in fact each image's metadata is actually full of information.  thanks.